# Who is this slave that prophet Muhammad traded 2 slaves for?

Tags: hadith

> It was narrated that jabir said **A slave came and pledged** to the Prophet to emigrate, and the Prophet did not realize that he was a slave. Then his master came looking for him. The Prophet said: 'Sell him to me,' and he bought him for two black slaves. Then he did not accept the pledge from anyone until he asked: 'Is he a slave?"' [ sunan an-nasai 4184 ]

Please somebody tell me the name/identity of this slave who pledged to the prophet

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of his name.

Comment: @TheZ dang.. but jazakallah for trying